# Issue with creating ComplexFilterPart

Tags: api, soap-api, marketing-cloud

I'm getting this error on ComplexFilterPart.  Does anyone know what's wrong with it?

Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'

If I set RetrieveRequest's Filter to one of the SimpleFilterPart, it works.  But setting it to the ComplexFilterPart gives this error.

Here's my code:

```
        $sfp1 = new ExactTarget_SimpleFilterPart();
        $sfp1->Property = "opt_in";
        $sfp1->Value =  array(1);
        $sfp1->SimpleOperator = ExactTarget_SimpleOperators::equals;

        $sfp2 = new ExactTarget_SimpleFilterPart();
        $sfp2->Property = "email_address";
        $sfp2->Value =  array('example@gmail.com');
        $sfp2->SimpleOperator = ExactTarget_SimpleOperators::equals;

        $cfp = new ExactTarget_ComplexFilterPart();
        $cfp->LeftOperand = $sfp1;
        $cfp->RightOperand = $sfp2;
        $cfp->LogicalOperator = ExactTarget_LogicalOperators::_AND;

        $rr = new ExactTarget_RetrieveRequest();
        $rr->ObjectType = "DataExtensionObject[Example_DE_Key]";
        $rr->Properties = array("email_address", "opt_in");
        $rr->Filter = new SoapVar($cfp, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'ComplexFilterPart', "http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI");
        //$rr->Filter = new SoapVar($sfp1, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'SimpleFilterPart', "http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI");
        //$rr->Filter = new SoapVar($sfp2, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, 'SimpleFilterPart', "http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI");

        $rrm = new ExactTarget_RetrieveRequestMsg(); 
        $rrm->RetrieveRequest = $rr;

        $results = $client->Retrieve($rrm);
        echo $results->OverallStatus;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you get this working?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have a typo -

```
$cfp->LogicalOperator = ExactTarget_LogicalOperators::_AND;
```

Should read

```
$cfp->LogicalOperator = ExactTarget_LogicalOperators::AND;
```